# Calcular estorno em porcentagem do valor final C#

Tags: c#, matemática, porcentagem

Boa noite, a pergunta é mais a respeito de cálculo do que programação. O problema é o seguinte: se eu vender algo devo acrescentar 15% de taxa de serviço.

```
var total = 100;
var acrescimoPercent = 15.00;
var acrescimo = total - (total / 100 * acrescimoPercent); 
total = total + acrescimo;
```

Ao todo terei uma venda de 115 reais, por exemplo. Mas caso eu precise fazer um estorno, não posso devolver a taxa de 15%. Porém agora eu tenho 115 e não posso aplicar os 15% de desconto por que ficaria com menos que o valor original (97,75), para devolver ao cliente.
Resumindo, preciso devolver os 100 reais mas não sei como aplicar a porcentagem para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem a fórmula:

```
resultado = valor * (1 + juros)
```

Usando seu exemplo teríamos:

```
var resultado = 100 * (1 + 0.15)  // resultado = 115
```

Se temos apenas juros e resultado e não temos valor, basta isolar `valor` na fórmula:

```
resultado = valor * (1 + juros)  // Fórmula inicial
valor * (1 + juros) = resultado  // Invertendo os lados
valor = resultado / (1 + juros)  // Divindo ambos os lados por (1 + juros)
```

Pronto, a fórmula final é:

```
valor = resultado / (1 + juros)
```

No seu exemplo ficaria

```
valor = 115 / (1 + 0.15)   // valor = 100
```

Comment: Entendi, não fiz esse cálculo no código, apenas na calculadora. Porém eu preciso voltar ao valor 100, tendo como base o valor final 115 e a taxa que é de 15%. Posso ter feito de maneira errada mas não consegui chegar ao resultado inicial de 100, seguindo seu exemplo. Irei tentar novamente

Comment: Como mencionei na resposta, basta você dividir o valor final por `1 + porcentagem`.. 15% é `0.15`.. então basta fazer o cálculo `115 / 1.15`

Comment: Cara desculpa, eu que fiz confusão estava certinho. Vlw cara, agradecido.